# Linking xml documents

Tags: xml

I am a beginner in xml, xquery and xpath. Is it possible to link two separate xml documents together based on a defined relationship between them? for example if I have an xml document containing all the customers of an online retail system like so (shortened example):

```
<customers>
<customer loyaltyPoints = "20" sex = "male">
    <customerID>1092</customerID>
    <first_name>James</first_name>
    <second_name>Roland</second_name>
    <email_address>jroland@eircom.net</email_address>
    <DOB>
        <day>07</day>
        <month>05</month>
        <year>1970</year>    
    </DOB>
    <orderlist>
        <order>[LINK TO ORDER FROM ORDERS.XML]</order>
    </orderlist>
</customer>
```

and a second xml file containing a series of orders like so:

```
<orders>
<order numberOfItems = "2">
    <orderID>384523</orderID>
    <items>
        <item>[LINK TO PRODUCT X IN PRODUCTS.XML]</item>
        <item>[LINK TO PRODUCT Y IN PRODUCTS.XML]</item>
    </items>
</order>
</orders>
```

Can I link the customer to the order in the other document and vice versa? Many Thanks

Comment: You want these combined into one xml document?

Comment: No they need to stay as separate xml documents, but I am trying to show how they interlink and reference eachother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the ID´s you have as keys for linking you can do the following:

```
XmlDocument customerDoc = new XmlDocument();
customerDoc.LoadXml("<customers>
                         <customer loyaltyPoints = \"20\" sex = \"male\">
                         <customerID>1092</customerID>
                         <first_name>James</first_name>
                         <second_name>Roland</second_name>
                         <email_address>jroland@eircom.net</email_address>
                         <DOB>
                             <day>07</day>
                             <month>05</month>
                             <year>1970</year>
                         </DOB>
                         <orderlist>
                             <order>384523</order>
                         </orderlist>
                       </customer>
                    </customers>");

XmlDocument ordersDoc = new XmlDocument();
ordersDoc.LoadXml("<orders>
                       <order numberOfItems = \"2\">
                           <orderID>384523</orderID>
                           <items>
                               <item>[LINK TO PRODUCT X IN PRODUCTS.XML]</item>
                               <item>[LINK TO PRODUCT Y IN PRODUCTS.XML]</item>
                           </items>
                        </order>
                   </orders>");

// Select all "customer" nodes
XmlNodeList nodes = customerDoc.SelectNodes("customers/customer");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
     XmlNodeList orderList = node.SelectNodes("orderlist");
     foreach (XmlNode orderNode in orderList)
     {
           string orderId = orderNode.InnerText;
           XmlNode orderInOrderDocNode = ordersDoc.SelectSingleNode("orders/order[orderID='" + orderId + "']");
           Console.WriteLine(orderInOrderDocNode.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

This will print out the order node that was found in the orders.xml document given the orderId that was in the customer document.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but thats not quite what I was trying to do. Im not sure its even possible, as theres very little information on the web about it. +1 for answer though!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but thats not quite what I was trying to do. Im not sure its even possible, as theres very little information on the web about it. +1 for answer though!